# In-Process Background task

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, background-task

I am new to background task, According to msdn article the In-Process background task will executed in application process.Is In-process background task will trigger if the application is not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is In-process background task will trigger if the application is not running?

Yes.

> In-process background tasks are simpler to implement than out-of-process background tasks. However, they are less resilient. If the code running in an in-process background task crashes, it will take down your app.
>
> Also note that DeviceUseTrigger, DeviceServicingTrigger and IoTStartupTask cannot be used with the in-process model. Activating a VoIP background task within your application is also not possible. These triggers and tasks are still supported using the out-of-process background task model.

Please check MSDN document for more details:[Create and register an in-process background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task)